# Where should I start?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, spacetime, resource-recommendations, education

My question may be strange but it is so necessary.

Although I am not a physicist student my professor demanded me to make a presentation about ( the geometry of spacetime )

What should I write or where should I start what are the main titles?

Comment: Very good and simple book is: Hans Reichenbach, The philosophy of Space and Time. I think it just what the doctor ordered. Just copy/paste. https://www.amazon.com/Philosophy-Space-Dover-Books-Physics/dp/0486604438

Comment: Did you try to read some overview articles already? [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org) may be a good place to start. Particularly, as they offer a section **Further reading** for many articles.

Comment: Try Einstein's lecture-book _The Meaning of Relativity_ , it has all you need. Starts with _Space time in pre-relativity physics_ ; then it takes you through _Special Relativity_ , then _General Relativity_; it has 2 nice add-ons _On the Cosmologic problem_ and _Relativistic theory of the non-symmetric field_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a little familiar with the special relativity and the Lorentz transformation I highly recommend "The Feynman Lectures on Physics" volume one, Chapter 17 is about the space-time.

You can read it [here](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_17.html)

But if you are not, I'd suggest first reading the chapter 15 of the same book. [Here](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_15.html). Which gets you familiar with the concept of special relativity, as without having knowledge about it no one can understand the geometry of space-time, and the [chapter 16](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html), which helps you understand it more and get ready for the chapter 17. and don't worry, by chapter, Fantastic Mr.Feynman means 15-20 pages of easy-to-understand delightful lecture!

Have fun studying physics!